# How to use Library from GitHub in android App

Tags: android, github, gradle, libraries

I downloaded [this library](https://github.com/jfmdev/aFileDialog) to use in my app, however, I can't get Android Studio to do the gradle build now. Anytime I try, I get "error:configuration with name 'default' not found". I've tried several other StackOverflow answers, but I still can't compile.

My dependencies (from build.gradle Module: app)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile project(":aFileDialog")
}
```

My settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':aFileDialog'
```

I have the library file in the root under "aFileDialog"

How can I get this to build with the library?

Comment: Does the `aFileDialog` folder contain a `build.gradle` file? It should.

Comment: Try to import aFileDialog project (File->New->Import project). You will have there an option to convert this project to gradle one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial that worked: http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/library-project-module-as-dependency-in-android-studio/

In addition to the instructions given, I had to add the following line to my Manifest:

```
    tools:replace = "icon, label"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have add path to your `aFileDialog` library in your `settings.gradle`

Make sure that folder you point to includes `build.gradle` file

```
include ':app'
include ':aFileDialog'
project(':aFileDialog').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'aFileDialog')
```

or (judging from the library folder structure on GitHub)

```
project(':aFileDialog').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'aFileDialog/library')
```